# Parse compound query with location

Tags: android, parse-platform

Is there a way to have a compound query with location in one of the queries. I need to have posting from within 3 miles and also have some posts that can be seen by everyone that have a specific boolean true.

The problem is, when I try to do this, it gives me a parse exception saying something like "geo queries not supported in or"

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I am doing. We have a 'Blast' class and a 'Activity' class. Blast are the items with geolocation nearby. Activity store the relationship for followers and followees. The trick I found somewhere else on the web (that I cannot remember) is to wrap the geo query in another query, and then all is good. In our case the 'nearbyItemsQueryWrapped' effectively 'wraps' the 'nearbyItemsQuery' so that we can do something extremely similar to what you are doing.

This is still not a perfect solution for our specific needs as it seems to have an issue with the items from the 'current' user - but it is darn close, and may meet your goals.

```
PFGeoPoint *point = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:location.latitude longitude:location.longitude];
    PFQuery *followeesQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kActivityObjectClassNameKey];
    [followeesQuery whereKey:kActivityFromUserKey equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [followeesQuery whereKey:kActivityTypeKey equalTo:kActivityTypeFollow];
    [followeesQuery whereKey:kActivityDeletedKey notEqualTo:@YES];

    PFQuery *nearbyItemsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kBlastObjectClassNameKey];
    [nearbyItemsQuery whereKey:kBlastLocationKey nearGeoPoint:point withinKilometers:kItemSearchRadius_Largest_Kilometers];
    [nearbyItemsQuery whereKey:kBlastFromUserKey doesNotMatchKey:kActivityToUserKey inQuery:followeesQuery];

    PFQuery *nearbyItemsQueryWrapped = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kBlastObjectClassNameKey];
    [nearbyItemsQueryWrapped whereKey:kBlastFromUserKey matchesKey:kBlastFromUserKey inQuery:nearbyItemsQuery];

    PFQuery *followersItemQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kBlastObjectClassNameKey];
    [followersItemQuery whereKey:kBlastFromUserKey matchesKey:kActivityToUserKey inQuery:followeesQuery];

    NSMutableArray *queryArray = NSMutableArray.new;
    [queryArray addObject:followersItemQuery];
    [queryArray addObject:nearbyItemsQueryWrapped];

    PFQuery* compoundQuery = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:queryArray];
    [compoundQuery includeKey:kBlastFromUserKey];
    [compoundQuery includeKey:kBlastCategoryKey];
    // unexpired only
    [compoundQuery whereKey:kBlastEndDateKey greaterThanOrEqualTo:[NSDate date]];
    // order them chronologically
    [compoundQuery orderByDescending:kBlastStartDateKey];
    // set up paging
    compoundQuery.limit = kQueryLimit;
    compoundQuery.skip = 0;
    // we don't want deleted items
    [compoundQuery whereKey:kBlastDeletedKey equalTo:@NO];        
    [compoundQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
```